# PHP: define constants outside a class or in the constructor?

Tags: php, oop, class, constructor, constants

i'm new to classes and oo.
I was looking for a basic MySQL class to start with, and i found "A Simple MySQL Class" by Matthew Saragusa.

These are the first lines:

```
define('SIMPLE_DB_SERVER', 'mysqlserver.net');
define('SIMPLE_DB_NAME', 'mydbname');
define('SIMPLE_DB_USERNAME', 'myusername');
define('SIMPLE_DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
class ASimpleMySQLDB {
    public function __construct($server, $database, $username, $password){

        $this->conn = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
        $this->db = mysql_select_db($database,$this->conn);
    }
[...]
```

I wonder if there is a specific reason for which constants are defined outside the class, rather than using the constructor - example:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
    $this->db = mysql_select_db('database',$this->conn);
}
```

Or:

```
public function __construct($which_db){
        if($which_db=='firstdb'){
            $server='localhost';
            $username='user1';
            $password='pass1';
            $database='db1';
        }elseif($which_db=='otherdb'){
            $server='localhost';
            $username='user2';
            $password='pass2';
            $database='db2';
        }

    $this->conn = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
    $this->db = mysql_select_db($database,$this->conn);

}
```

Or using a switch or whatever.

What is the difference between the two methods? Which would you recommend? Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: How about defining them in an .ini file :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though it's largely discouraged by most OO PHP developers nowadays, many libraries still employ `define()` to set configuration constants that will need to be modified by the end party implementing the library.  These are usually stowed away in a configuration file that is required/included by the class that needs this configuration information, or is included even further back up the stack if its needed globally (Wordpress comes to mind.)

PHP 5 includes class constants to fulfill this same function but only in the scope of the class itself.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

This approach is a good way to create class specific, unchangeable values that your library is going to need.  Since one of the primary goals of employing OOP in PHP is code re-usability, this packages the configuration nicely for release.  In the case of your database class, you could have `const` declarations before your construct method defining all the access credentials, such as the db_host, db_user and db_pass.  Please note that these constants have to be accessed by `ClassName::ConstName` much like a static method would.

Although OOP in PHP has come a long way and is now widespread, a ton of older or more "locked in" frameworks and libraries still use the define convention, so you'll see it very commonly used even in OO environments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just what i hoped to hear.

Comment: If you're just learning too, I'd suggest reading as much as you can of the class chapter of the PHP documentation.  It really helps on understand core things like static vs instantiate methods and object inheritance.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Even having long since made the switch to Python from PHP on my team, the quality and scope of PHP's documentation is still something I really miss!

Comment: I learned php self taught, now I'm reading a book by Peter MacIntyre
shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596804381.do
Unfortunately i am italian, although i am familiar with english, technical language is still difficult to me :-)

Answer (score 3):

1. So other files/classes can access the defined value (GLOBAL)
2. Easier to edit in case you are going to change your db in future

The best way to implement this is to create a configuration file with all of this definitions.
i.e

configuration.php

```
define('SIMPLE_DB_SERVER', 'mysqlserver.net');
define('SIMPLE_DB_NAME', 'mydbname');
define('SIMPLE_DB_USERNAME', 'myusername');
define('SIMPLE_DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
```

and include them into your MySQL connection class connection.php

```
include "configuration.php";

class DBConnection 
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->conn = mysql_connect(SIMPLE_DB_SERVER, SIMPLE_DB_USERNAME, SIMPLE_DB_PASSWORD);
        $this->db = mysql_select_db(SIMPLE_DB_NAME,$this->conn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the specific context of that particular MySQL connection class, but the difference between defining the connection info as constants rather than class properties is one of scope.

The constants are available anywhere in the codebase after that particular line of code has run, so you can access them outside of the ASimpleMySQLDB class. Any variables defined within the constructor, on the other hand, would not work outside of the class.

Oftentimes, I find that people use constants at the beginning of their code to set values that will need to be modified (usually only once) by the end user (WordPress uses this in their wp-config.php file http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php ). This way, people don't have to dig into the class itself to find where to set the DB connection values. I'm guessing this readability factor is why this particular author has decided to use constants.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! So there is no other reason than to make them available outside the class? Since they will not be used by other parts of code (that's why i want a class to manage database connections) I would put them within the constructor.
thanks again

Comment: Yup. Going along with what DeaconDesperado said, it's mostly a convention at this point, and it does mean your MySQL connection info is available in the codebase outside the connection class, which doesn't help security.

Answer (score 0):

Constants defined ones and in one place. And In your examples other developers would have to search where the database parameters are.

Answer (score 0):

This separation is most likely because the `ASimpleMySQLDb` class is a wrapper around a database.  This is a general class, so to make it specific by hard coding connection details in the constructor would make it so you couldn't re-use it.  You want to maintain that flexibility even within a single application as you may end up with several databases.

Personally, I tend to create an `Application` class that follows the singleton pattern and declare my database connection details as `static` variables within that class.  This allows me to still easily change my database connection information or add additional databases as needed.